# Test class helper library issue ( ImportError: cannot import name 'Test' )

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-databricks

I was working with a normal wordcount spark application on Databricks.
To use the helper library I used spark._mooc_meta library in my cluster.

After which I have expected to get output as 1 test passed for below code. But getting some different issue.

```
    from databricks_test_helper import Test

    Test.assertEquals(wordCountsDF.collect(), [(tutorial, 1), (spark, 2),
    (look, 2), (python, 1)],
    'incorrect counts for wordCountsDF')
```

Output : ImportError: cannot import name 'Test'

Below is the python and Scala version used:
Python version : 3
Databricks Runtime version : 5.2 (Spark 2.4 and scala 2.11)

Comment: It seems that is on PyPI. Do you have the package installed on the cluster or in the notebook session?

Comment: Yes, I was using it on Azure Databricks. Recently I found that its working fine with python 2 , but while using Python version 3 we are getting this issue. Any suggestions how it will work with python 3 ?